# Matlab loadlibrary call, using a network file?

Tags: windows, matlab, dll, loadlibrary, unc

On Windows, Matlab's [`loadlibrary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html) appears to expect a library located on a mapped drive.

What if I want to load a library on a network file share, and in order to make my script useable by many people, I don't want to have to assume that they have all mapped their drives similarly.  I'd prefer to use a filename of the form:  `\\baseName\dirname\libarary.dll`

Is there a way to do that with `loadlibrary`?

Comment: @Amro does it make sense to edit the title as well?

Comment: if you think it will make the post clearer then go for it, it is your question after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Matlab understands network file names.  The issue, was with a network server with some erroneous mappings, nothing to do with matlab.